# GStreamer and PLS Files

Tags: java, gstreamer

I'm not able to play PLS files using the GStreamer, does anybody knows if that file format is supported by the GStreamer framework?

Comment: How are you playing it? Do you have some code somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are playlists and not media files. Use a library such as totem-plparser for them.